# Prove $(x_n)$ does not converge to real number $x$ using definition

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, epsilon-delta

$x_n$ = $(-1)^n(1-{1\over n})$

Prove: If $x$ ∈ $\Bbb{R}$ is any real number, then ($x_n$) does not converge to $x$.

This has to be proved using the negation of the definition i.e.

$\exists{\varepsilon}>0$, $\forall{N∈\Bbb{N}}$, $\exists{n}>N$ : $|x_n-x|\ge\varepsilon$

Comment: Have you calculated the first, say, $5$ or $10$ terms of this sequence? Can you guess how it's behaving? Without at least some understanding of how the sequence moves, you won't be able to prove why it doesn't converge.

Comment: @Arthur The sequence alternates

Comment: Exactly. Now, why would that mean that there exists an $\varepsilon$ such as the one you describe above? One candidate could be $\varepsilon =1/2$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose $\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n=x\in \mathbb{R}$ Let $\epsilon=\frac{1}{4}$

Suppose $x\leq 0, \forall n>1,(-1)^{2n}(1-{1\over 2n})>\frac{1}{2}$,  Hence $\forall N\in \mathbb{N}$, pick $n=2N>N$, then 
$$|(-1)^{n}(1-{1\over n})-x|=(-1)^{n}(1-{1\over n})-x\geq(-1)^{n}(1-{1\over n})>\frac{1}{2}>\epsilon$$

Similarly for $x> 0$ by considering $n$ is odd.

By definition, it doesn't converge to any real number.

Answer (score 1):

$\exists{\varepsilon}>0, \forall{N∈\Bbb{N}}, \exists{n}>N : |x_n-x|\ge\varepsilon$

Let's take $\varepsilon = \frac{1}{2}$. $\forall n > 1: |x_n| \geq \frac{1}{2}$ and $|x_n - x_{n+1}| \geq 1$. Then even if for some $n$: $|x_n - x| < \varepsilon$ then $|x_{n+1} - x| = |x_{n+1} - x_n + x_n - x| \geq |x_{n+1} - x_n| - |x_n - x| > 1- \varepsilon$.